# How to apply changes on current fragment when opening new fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have managed to switch between fragment, but the changes on current fragment doesn't applied when entering a new fragment. I have 2 fragments, `HomeFragment` and `Sublisting`. When I first run the app, it shows `HomeFragment` which is showing `football` content. If I click action bar, it will change into Subreddit fragment. In `Sublisting` fragment, I can click a subreddit category (e.g. `basketball`, `tennis`, etc.). After I click a subreddit category, the fragment change to `HomeFragment` again where it should shows the content of subreddit category I just choose, but it doesn't. I choose `tennis` while in `Sublisting` fragment, but it still showing the first subreddit category when I run my app, which is `football`.

Here is my `SublistingListAdapter.kt`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
    val binding = RowSubredditBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
        parent, false)
    val holder = VH(binding)
    
    return holder
}
```

Here is my `HomeFragment.kt`:

```
class HomeFragment: Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
    private var _binding: FragmentRvBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): HomeFragment {
            return HomeFragment()
        }
    }
   
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentRvBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "onViewCreated")

        initAdapter(binding)
    }
}
```

I thought by using `updateNewCategory` and `observeNewCategory` would change the subreddit category, but turns out it didn't. How to update the category and apply the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am understanding with your code snippet is that your are trying to use common MainViewModel to communicate among your fragments and Activity.

Your issue is that you are creating new instance of MainViewModel in your fragment by using `private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()` instead of using `activityViewModel`

Use following line to get viewModel reference of your activity in your fragment

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
```